# Formally, why does a logical contradiction have probability zero?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In terms of formal probability theory, why does an event representing a logical contradiction (such as $A \wedge \neg A$) always have probability zero?

I understand intuitively why this is the case, but I don't see anything in the [axioms of probability](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProbabilityAxioms.html) that directly explains why $A \wedge \neg A$ must have probability zero (or, equivalently, why a logical tautology such as $A \vee \neg A$ must have probability 1).

Comment: Formally, the axioms assign a probability to *sets*, not to formulas. So you would definitely understand more about the axiomatization if you stop thinking about murky concepts like "the probability of $A \wedge \neg A$".

Answer (score 51, accepted):

We see that in probability, we represent the event $A$ as a set of elements in our sample space, and $\neg A$ as the complement of $A$ in our sample space. Thus, in probabilistic terms,

$$P(A \wedge \neg A) = P\left(A \cap \overline{A}\right) = P(\emptyset)$$

by the definition of the complement. And by the Kolmogorov Axioms, we see that

$$P(\emptyset) = 0.$$

Comment: And, in case it isn't obvious, the reason that necessarily $P(\emptyset) = 0.$ is that if it were nonzero, you could add two empty sets and get an identical empty set with a higher probability.

Comment: One can phrase this a bit more generally.  Whenever the defining conditions of some event $X$ are logically contradictory, that means that $X$ is empty, and so again we have $P(X) = P(\emptyset) = 0$.

Comment: @ThomSmith I think that would be a useful improvement. A few sets here, a few sets there, and pretty soon you are talking real... sets.

Answer (score 5):

Your axiom list states that

> 3. Additivity: $P(E_1 \cup E_2)=P(E_1)+P(E_2)$, where  $E_1$ and $E_2$ are mutually exclusive.

Note that $A \wedge \neg A$ is mutually exlusive with itself.

Hence $$P(A \wedge\neg A)=P\left((A \wedge \neg A)\cup(A \wedge \neg A)\right) = P(A \wedge\neg A) + P(A \wedge\neg A) $$

Answer (score 4):

As booleans, boolean-valued functions, boolean-valued random variables, or any other similar sort of thing, $A \wedge \neg A$ is the same thing as "false", and $A \vee \neg A$ is the same thing as "true".

Applying this, your question reduces to

> Why is $P(\text{true}) = 1$ and $P(\text{false}) = 0$?

Answering this depends on the exact details you want things in terms of, but basically $\text{true}$ is always true and $\text{false}$ is never true.

e.g. if, when $X$ is a boolean-valued random variable you define $P(X)$ to mean the probability of the event consisting of exactly those samples where $X$ is true, then $P(\text{true})$ would be the probability of the entire sample space.

Answer (score -1):

A logical contradiction can never be true.   Something that surely will never happen (an impossibility) has probability measure of zero.

A tautology will always be true.   Something that surely will happen (a certainty) has a probability measure of one.

That is all.

Comment: OP was asking for a formal argument, not another heuristic one.